# Pegar array de dados de uma API via Java

Tags: java, api, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Tenho uma API com um array de dados.Exemplo:

```
"bandeiras" : [
     {
            "bandeira": "MASTER",
            "status": "ATIVO"
          },
          {
            "bandeira": "HIPER",
            "status": "ATIVO"
          } ]
```

O que eu tenho que fazer para pegar os dados de cada bandeira, e isso quando eu clicar no botão  **<kbd>pegar bandeiras</kbd>** , para na última jsp do projeto ele exibir todas essas bandeiras com os valores.

Criei o DTO com os valores do retorno da API.
Porém, não sei como vou fazer para tratar isso no controller quando eu clicar no botão na jsp, já que ele só tem que exibir no fim do fluxo.

Alguma dica/solução?

Comment: Sem nada do seu código para avaliarmos é impossível te dar uma solução: [Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%C3%83o-fazer-perguntas/5484#5484).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você já setou esse seu array em um objeto do tipo Bandeiras?
Caso já tenha setado, é só passar o array pro front.

```
<c:forEach items="${bandeiras}" var="bandeira">
<tr>      
    <td>${bandeira.bandeira}</td>
    <td>${bandeira.status}</td>
</tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Caso contrário, atualiza aí o que já foi feito, abraço